Is this a valid way of showing that $R$ with infinity and negative infinity is not a vector space?
Section 1B Exercise 6 Linear Algebra Done Right
I want to see if this is a valid way of showing that the problem from the image above is not a vector space.
Disproof
By how we defined scalar multiplication on $\infty$ and -$\infty$,
2*$\infty$ = 6*$\infty$
we add the additive inverse of 6*$\infty$ to both sides,
2*$\infty$ + (-6$\infty$) = 0*$\infty$
we use the distributive property,
(2-6)$\infty$ = 0*$\infty$
-4*$\infty$ = 0*$\infty$
-$\infty$ = 0.
However, this implies that -$\infty$ is the additive identity which contradicts the fact that,
t + -$\infty$ = -$\infty$ for any t $\in$ $R$.
This looks correct, but I feel like I cheated somewhere. Does this look valid? Any hints on how to approach this problem if my method is incorrect?

Why write $0\times \infty$ instead of just $0$?  Then you get $4\times \infty=0$ contradicting the definition $4\times \infty = \infty$.

That's true. I suppose I just wanted to show 0*$\infty$ as a vector throughout the problem. I can see that my last two lines are unnecessary if the logic beforehand is correct.

Just to keep ir efficient, I'd write $2\times \infty=\infty\implies \infty=0$.

In the extended real numbers $0\times \infty$ is left undefined.

To be a vector space $+$ has to be a group operation.
Suppose $+$ is a group operation in the extended reals. Then $0 + \infty = \infty = 1 + \infty$. Subtracting $\infty$ from both sides yields $0 = 1$, a contradiction.
